Filter coefficients not working when directly implemented on to a audio file?
When I use the butter function from scipy for a bandpass filter of order 4 onto a .wav audio file, it is working but when I use the same filter coefficients directly on to the same audio it is not working.
I'm trying to implement a bandpass filter on a .wav audio file using Python. Initially, I used the butter function from scipy to generate filter coefficients and applied the filter using filtfilt, which worked fine. However, when I tried to directly use the same filter coefficients with lfilter, I didn't get the expected results. Here's what I've tried:
First, here's the code that worked using filtfilt:
from scipy.signal import butter, filtfilt
from scipy.io import wavfile

def butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=4):
    nyq = 0.5 * fs
    low = lowcut / nyq
    high = highcut / nyq
    b, a = butter(order, [low, high], btype='band')
    return b, a

def butter_bandpass_filter(data, lowcut, highcut, fs, order=4):
    b, a = butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=order)
    y = filtfilt(b, a, data)
    return y

filename = "Heart Data 1 (1).wav"
fs, data = wavfile.read(filename)

lowcut = 30
highcut = 450
order = 4

b, a = butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=order)
print("Filter Coefficients (b):", b)
print("Filter Coefficients (a):", a)

filtered_data = butter_bandpass_filter(data, lowcut, highcut, fs, order=order)

This code produced the desired filtered audio with the coefficients
b = [3.76138361e-05, 0.00000000e+00, -1.50455344e-04, 0.00000000e+00,
     2.25683017e-04, 0.00000000e+00, -1.50455344e-04, 0.00000000e+00,
     3.76138361e-05]
a = [1.0, -7.56134654, 25.03021633, -47.37940103, 56.09188775,
     -42.53071304, 20.16985559, -5.46999014, 0.64949108]

However, when I tried to use the same filter coefficients directly with lfilter, I didn't get the expected results:
from scipy.signal import lfilter
from scipy.io import wavfile

filename = "Heart Data 1 (1).wav"
fs, data = wavfile.read(filename)

b = [3.76138361e-05, 0.00000000e+00, -1.50455344e-04, 0.00000000e+00,
     2.25683017e-04, 0.00000000e+00, -1.50455344e-04, 0.00000000e+00,
     3.76138361e-05]
a = [1.0, -7.56134654, 25.03021633, -47.37940103, 56.09188775,
     -42.53071304, 20.16985559, -5.46999014, 0.64949108]

filtered_data = lfilter(b, a, data)

This code didn't produce the desired filtered audio.
I expected both methods to produce the same filtered audio since I used the same filter coefficients. Can someone help me understand what might be going wrong with the second method using lfilter? Thank you!

Lfilter is different than filtfilt.
lfilter method applies filtering once, using standard method
a[0]*y[n] = b[0]*x[n] + b[1]*x[n-1] + ... + b[nb]*x[n-nb]
                        - a[1]*y[n-1] - ... - a[na]*y[n-na]

filtfilt method applies filtering twice, each time using the standard method as above, but second time it does it with reversed signal. So:

it removes delay (to be precise, adds delay twice but second one cancels the first one)
since signal is filtered twice it can be interpreted as doubling filter order

